# What's wrong with the non capture group in my regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match a strings similar to the ones below:

```
Yu MSBE26
w AWAQBNL
```

I am using Javascript and have come up with the following regular expression:

```
(.*?(?:[AWMS\d]{2})[AWMS\d]{2}[A-Z]{2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,3})
```

In words, I start my capture group off by matching everything until the `[AWMS\d]{2}` pattern is encountered, then I match the `[AWMS\d]{2}` pattern, the `[A-Z]{2}` that follows and finally the `[\dA-Za-z]{1,3}` to match the final two or three characters.

From what I have read, this should be working, but I'm not getting any matches.

For example when I use a regex tester I don't get any matches: [Sample](http://regex101.com/r/zF6lC9/2)

Comment: Can you share a few more of your expected matches and non-matches? [This doesn't work](http://regex101.com/r/xM8tR1/1) (obviously) and it's hard to know what you expect to work.

Comment: I edited my question to include my samples in a regex tester. I'm trying to match the two strings and its not obvious to me why I'm not matching.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not matching because your non-capture group is duplicated again after the NC group. Guessing this is a mistake. Remove it and it works fine.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor your regex fails matching your string because doesn't match the pattern as I detailed in my answer.

Comment: Is `a-Z` is typo in `[\dA-Za-Z]{1,3}`? If not then it will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second `[AWMS\d]{2}` - it looks like an accidental addition and is the reason your regex doesn't [work](http://regex101.com/r/xM8tR1/3):

```
(.*?(?:[AWMS\d]{2})[A-Z]{2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,3})
```

**Edit:** you don't even need the non capture group, the square brackets are enough:

```
(.*?[AWMS\d]{2}[A-Z]{2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,3})
```

Comment: The first [AWMS\d] is part of the the non capture group.  I'm using the second to actually match, no? Or am I not understanding how non-capture groups work.  I thought the .*? would match up to the MS in the first string, due to the non capture group. Then I match from there.

Comment: You only need it once in your pattern. If you used a regular capture group it would literally capture those two letters/digits as well as the overall pattern ([see example](http://regex101.com/r/xM8tR1/4)), but you don't need a capture/NC group at all because your square brackets do the trick just fine.

Comment: [See here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28.*%3F%5BAWMS%5Cd%5D%7B2%7D%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%5B%5CdA-Za-z%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%29) for an explanation of what your regex does (without NC/C group)

Comment: I can't argue with success, thanks. Am I wrong in thing that the non-capture group doesn't capture.

Comment: A non-capture group doesn't capture. But if its inside a capture group, the contents of the NC group will still be captured in the parent capture group. [See my comment on the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320941/whats-wrong-with-the-non-capture-group-in-my-regular-expression/25320989#comment39470889_25321001)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match your values because simply they don't match.

Your pattern is:

```
(.*?(?:[AWMS\d]{2})[AWMS\d]{2}[A-Z]{2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,3})

Yu MSBE26
     ^--- fails here
w AWAQBNL
     ^--- fails here
```

Btw, you can use your regex to match your strings as this:

```
(.*?[AWMS\d]{2}[A-Z]{2}[\dA-Za-z]{1,3})
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kU5cP0/1)**

Comment: Thanks. Your demo works great, but it does not use a non-capture group.  I need to use one as this is only a piece of a bigger regular expression.

Comment: Doesn't the [A-Z]{2} match the BE and AQ. My understanding is that a non capture group does not match. Therefore, the second [AWMS\d]{2} would match MA, the [A-Z]{2} would match BE and the [\dA-Za-z]{1,3} would match 26.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor yes, `[A-Z]{2}` matches the BE and AQ. The **capturing** part is controller by the `()` brackets on the left and right ends of your string. Everything that matches and is within those brackets will be "captured" and returned from the regex. If you had to have a second set of brackets `()` within that group, and you didn't want them to be returned twice (because its another capture group it would), **that** is when you should use a non capture group to negate it. They are still captured in the overall group. In your case, you don't need an inner group at all though.