# Is it possible to write a regular expression that skips a character or characters and continues matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression that work for the majority string patterns. There is one pattern, however, that is not matching and I'm having difficulty figuring out.

```
(.*?(?:[AWMS]{2}|\d{1,2})\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*(?:[A-Z3]{1,3}|[^A]\d{1,2}))
```

I have [sample matches](http://regex101.com/r/zF6lC9/7) here.

The string pattern that I'm having difficulty with follows:

```
v MSWO 2A4  =>  yields v MSWO 2 but I want this v MSWO 24 (skipping the A)
```

I tried using several variants of [^A] but this is really saying match everything but A, and that's not exactly what I want.

I'm using Javascript.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't need the outer parentheses at all, since the entire match is returned anyway by functions such as `String#match`. You also don't need the `.*?` at the beginning, since `match`, `test` etc. will find the match wherever it is within the string.

Comment: I'm string to skip a charter (the A in the sample above) and match the v MSWO 24.

Comment: Is there some problem with `A?`?

Comment: @torazaburo this is part of a larger expression and the outer parenthesis are meant to be a capture group.

Comment: If you are trying to find a regex that will cause `match()` to exclude certain parts of the match from the returned value, I don't think that will work. Perhaps you can use `replace()` to remove those unwanted parts and then `match()` afterwards? Or you could put the unwanted parts in separate groups and then concatenate the matched groups that you do want?

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320941/whats-wrong-with-the-non-capture-group-in-my-regular-expression

Comment: not a duplicate. Different issue and different question.

Comment: You can't, regular expressions are a regular language. Just use a regex replacement, and replace `"A"` to `""`

Comment: I've never used regex replacement. I will read up on it and give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but let's break down the syntax and see what is matching. Maybe this will help you develop a better regex!

To eliminate confusion, your linked example had the regex without the `[^A]` near the end:

```
(.*?(?:[AWMS]{2}|\d{1,2})\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*(?:[A-Z3]{1,3}|\d{1,2}))
```

The first `.*?` at the very beginning matches `"v "`.

Then `[AWMS]{2}` matches `"MS"`. The first `\s*` afterwards matches nothing--a star can match 0.

Then `[A-Z]{2}` matches `"WO"`, so far so good...

The next `\s*` matches one space.

Then in the next group, `[A-Z3]{1,3}` doesn't match `"2"`, so the pipe `|` kicks in and allows `\d{1,2}` to be evaluated, which happily matches `"2"`.

Annnd we're done!

I'm not 100% on what you're trying to do but it appears you want that string without the A...in which case you want to match the whole string, but do away with certain parts of it.
So I would take out the outer capturing group and use capturing groups in small parts.

```
(.*?)([AWMS]{2}|\d{1,2})(\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*)([A-Z3]{1,3}|\d{1,2})(?:A?)(\d{1,2})?
```

Now a replacement string of `$1$2$3$4$5` will turn `"v MSWO 2A4"` into `"v MSWO 24"`.

Note I added the very last `?` because I saw without it, the matching changed on the last line of your samples...I thought the part the extra question mark qualifies an omission on your part (my best guess) that you need to match the last `4`, but perhaps it's not necessarily there.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Still not sure I totally follow the replacement string part, but I'll get there.

Comment: If you use regular parentheses `()` inside regex, you not only group matches but "remember" them for later if you are using `replace()`. The syntax `$n` calls up one of the backreferences where `n` is a 1-based index in the order of capturing groups as specified by `()`. So, in this case, `$1` refers to the "junk at the beginning" group, `(.*?)`. 

Note however non-capturing groups (`(?:)`) do not create backreferences.